# Simple Top, Bottom, & Scrollable Div Layout does not work on mobile

Tags: html, css

Here is my reproducible code:
https://codepen.io/ReMuSoMeGA93/pen/zYMqbPZ

I'm making a messenger app. Whenever a message is added, the message immediately breaks out of the .MessageWrapper div and overlaps the .top div.

To reproduce this, focus on the "response" input, then see everything get pushed up immediately and break out. Only does this in Mobile Safari & Chrome.

In my production, this isnt how I normally reproduce it - I just trigger a new message to be added to the chat, and it happens. But somehow focusing on the input does the same thing.

```
<HTML>
  <body>
       <div class='container flex h-screen'>

        <div class="top">

      <form>
      <input type="text" 
      class="pubmed_input" 
      placeholder="Pubmed Query..." 
      </form>

        </div>

        
<div class="middle">
    <div class="messageWrapper">
<div key={index} class='message helper'>
                    <pre>Helper: some text here and here and here and hereand here and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and herehere and here and hereand here and here and here</pre>
                </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <div class="bottom">

    <form>

    <input type="text"  class='response_input'  placeholder="Response..." />
    </form>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --max-width: 1100px;
  --border-radius: 12px;
  --font-mono: ui-monospace, Menlo, Monaco, 'Cascadia Mono', 'Segoe UI Mono',
    'Roboto Mono', 'Oxygen Mono', 'Ubuntu Monospace', 'Source Code Pro',
    'Fira Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace;

  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;

  --primary-glow: conic-gradient(
    from 180deg at 50% 50%,
    #16abff33 0deg,
    #0885ff33 55deg,
    #54d6ff33 120deg,
    #0071ff33 160deg,
    transparent 360deg
  );
  --secondary-glow: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
  );

  --tile-start-rgb: 239, 245, 249;
  --tile-end-rgb: 228, 232, 233;
  --tile-border: conic-gradient(
    #00000080,
    #00000040,
    #00000030,
    #00000020,
    #00000010,
    #00000010,
    #00000080
  );

  --callout-rgb: 238, 240, 241;
  --callout-border-rgb: 172, 175, 176;
  --card-rgb: 180, 185, 188;
  --card-border-rgb: 131, 134, 135;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;

    --primary-glow: radial-gradient(rgba(1, 65, 255, 0.4), rgba(1, 65, 255, 0));
    --secondary-glow: linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0),
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0),
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0.3)
    );

    --tile-start-rgb: 2, 13, 46;
    --tile-end-rgb: 2, 5, 19;
    --tile-border: conic-gradient(
      #ffffff80,
      #ffffff40,
      #ffffff30,
      #ffffff20,
      #ffffff10,
      #ffffff10,
      #ffffff80
    );

    --callout-rgb: 20, 20, 20;
    --callout-border-rgb: 108, 108, 108;
    --card-rgb: 100, 100, 100;
    --card-border-rgb: 200, 200, 200;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;  /* Adjust this value according to your needs */
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  margin-top: 50px; /* This should be equal to or greater than the height of .top */
  position: relative;
}

.messageWrapper {
  flex: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;  /* Adjust this value according to your needs */
    width: 100%;
}


.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('/static/symbiote/bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0.7; /* Adjust the opacity as needed */
  z-index: -1;
}

.messageWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px; /* You can adjust this */
    height: 10px; 
}

.messageWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #3B82F6;
    border-radius: 0; /* This makes it square */
}

.messageWrapper {
    scrollbar-color: #3B82F6 transparent; /* For Firefox and some other browsers */
    scrollbar-width: thin; /* For Firefox */
    scrollbar-color: #3B82F6 transparent;
    /* ...other styles... */
}

.message {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  margin-top: 0.7rem;
  min-width: 0;
}

.message pre {
  white-space: 'pre-line';
  overflow-wrap: break-all;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}

.me {
  background-color: #0F172A;
  color: #66B2FF;
}


.helper {
  background-color: #0c2e5d;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.8; /* Adjust the opacity as needed */
}

.system {
  background-color: #171717;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.ai {
  background-color: #1F2937;
  color: #66B2FF;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.pubmed_input {
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #233c85;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.response_input {
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #4b83ee;
  color: #FFF;
}

@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
   input {
     font-size: 16px;
   }
}
```

I've tried adding this, "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" as I've seen in other SO posts, but nothing has changed.